# Selected items not displayed the DropdownButton in Flutter

Tags: flutter

i am a beginner of flutter.iam creating a DropdownButton to list the items.item was loading well on DropdownButton .but loading item selected not displayed at the DropdownButton i don't know. what i tried so far i attached below.
what is the wrong here **onChanged: (value) => setState(() => this.valueschoose = value,**

```
DropdownButton<String>(
                    items: <String>['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'].map((String value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Text(value),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (value) => setState(() => this.valueschoose = value,
    
                  )),
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing this `value` of dropdown button

```
DropdownButton<String>(
                    value: this.valueschoose,
                    items: <String>['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'].map((String value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Text(value),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (value) => setState(() => this.valueschoose = value,
    
                  )),
```